# How do I obtain the response from google volley on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, android-volley

How do I obtain the response from google volley?  I'm able to display the response in my logcat using System.out.println("Volley"+response);

I cant figure out how to pull it out of the google volley function.  Heres my code:

```
final String url = MAIN_URL;

        // prepare the Request
         StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,

                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            System.out.println("Volley"+response);
                                 //I want to be able to get this response and use it in other functions.

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            System.out.println("Error"+error);
                        }
                    }); 

        // add it to the RequestQueue  
         sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    10000, 
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        queue.add(sr);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _obtain_?

Answer (score 0):

I always put queue into singleton - Application and request can be called and received wherewer in the code, fom example:

[android volley caching asynchronous requests - How te get url of the request in ResponseListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433859/android-volley-caching-asynchronous-requests-how-te-get-url-of-the-request-in)

So you just create your own response listener in the class where you need it